# How to kill Bazel server process on Windows 11?

Tags: windows, bazel

How do I kill the Bazel server process on Windows 11?

On Windows 10 I used the task manager to identify all Open JDK processes and killed some - most of the time I deleted this way the Bazel Server or some other Java application.

On Windows 11 I do not see any OpenJDK processes anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get Bazel sever PID

```
bazel info server_pid
```

Use taskkill to delete Bazel server via its PID:

```
taskkill /F /PID <bazel_server_pid>
```